# Bash script strange behavior - script does not act as manual commands

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ubuntu

So, this is strange. When I manually run commands it all works fine, but when I run a script with identical commands, I get strange error output.

This is what I run:

```
lxc list;
for elem in {001..005}; do lxc stop ubuntu-"$elem"; done;
for elem in {001..005}; do lxc start ubuntu-"$elem"; done;
lxc list;
```

When I do that manually, all works with no error and my command have an actual effect. LXD machines are actually getting stopped and started again.

However, if I just write this as a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
lxc list;
for elem in {001..005}; do lxc stop ubuntu-"$elem"; done;
for elem in {001..005}; do lxc start ubuntu-"$elem"; done;
lxc list;
```

I get errors (very uninformative ones, I guess about not finding machines to run command against).

```
error: not found
error: not found
```

For both loop commands.

I'm new here so please advise.

Comment: This looks like you've got some difference in environmental variables or their values between your login shell, and the `/bin/bash` that runs the script. Can you run `printenv` in a script and see if that matches `printenv` output from the interactive (login) shell?

Comment: How exactly are you executing the script?

Comment: @BruceEdiger I will try and I presume a diff of both outputs should help?
steeldriver sh script.sh

Comment: @BruceEdiger I did output both script and login shell printenv and vimdiffed those - differences are vast. What can or what should I do about that?

Comment: Can you run the script with `sh -x script` and paste the output?

Comment: -x Did not help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{001..005}`  is a bash feature but you are running your script with sh and on Ubuntu sh is dash not bash.

So don't run your script with `sh script.sh` but with `bash script.sh` or even simply `./script.sh` since you have `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: You were correct. Running with bash was fine. Obviously sh on Ubuntu 15.04 links to dash which does not support a 'for loop'; not the same way bash does.
However, running ./ did not work: asked for permission, but with *sudo* it also just outputs "command not found". Why is that so?

Comment: You need to give execution permission to your script, typically with  `chmod +x script.sh` to run it with `./script.sh`.   I am not sure what happens with sudo in this case.